# Ajax pass values to datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, datetimepicker

I'm working on a code to dynamically set daysOfWeekDisabled in a dateTimePicker using Ajax.

I've got problem with the daysOfWeekDisabled's array. 
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#daysofweekdisabled

Here is the code.

html:

```
<div id="show-pic" class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="datepicker" name="delivery_time" type="text" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="Choose a delivery time"/>
</div>
```

script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../ajax.php',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY - H:mm',
            minDate: new Date(),
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [result]
        });
    }
});
```

ajax.php:

```
$week_day = array('0','6');
$string = implode(',', $week_day);
echo $string;
```

The console returns 0,6... great! but only Sunday is disable, 6 is ignored.

I tried several thing like "json_encode" or the "join()" function but can't get it.

Kindly please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the datepicker, is daysOfWeekDisabled supposed to be an array?

Comment: Yes, it is. 
=> http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#daysofweekdisabled

Comment: I'm not familiar either, but what happens if you do `$week_day = array('1','7');`?

Comment: Also what happens when you do it without the ajax call? Just setting it in Javascript as an array?

Comment: @timgavin : With ('1', '7'), only monday will be disable =>  "daysOfWeekDisabled Default: [] Accepts: array of numbers from 0-6"

Comment: @fauxserious : Without ajax call, it works perfectly.
daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6] disables well saturday and monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what the problem is after asking some questions.  I believe the php is returning a string back to your javascript, not an array (even though it might look like one).  So in php use `echo json_encode($week_day);`

In the ajax response use `JSON.parse(result)` to turn it back into an array.  You might be able to set `dataType: json` in the ajax call instead to have the result parsed when it comes back but I've had problems with that sometimes.  If you `console.log(result)` and you cannot twirl down the array as values (meaning it doesn't explicitly say `Array[2]` with an arrow to twirl down) it's probably a string. Check out what you get with `console.log(JSON.parse(result))` instead.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it in few minutes. Brb

Comment: Alright, you lead me to right track. 

I post the solution.

Comment: The JSON.parse(result) returned some errors like "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data".

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I had to use "json_encode" (thank you @fauxserious).

So the code now.

script:

```
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../ajax.php',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY - H:mm',
        minDate: new Date(),
        daysOfWeekDisabled: result
      });
    }
  });
```

ajax.php:

```
$week_day = array(0, 6);
  echo(json_encode($week_day));
```

Thank you all!

Comment: `daysOfWeekDisabled : result` should work (without brackets)

Comment: Right! 

Thank you again!

I have to do the same with the opening hours of the shop...

Your help is really useful.